# Pasar una variable de JS a una consulta MySQL en PHP

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Quiero que de JS mande los valores a una consulta SQL en PHP, lo que me pasa es lo siguiente:

```
<script language="javascript">
   function fAgrega(){
     var arrayDeCadenas = document.getElementById("nombredocente").value;
<?php 
        $lastname = "arrayDeCadenas[0];";
        $name = "arrayDeCadenas[1];";
        $pru = "SELECT * FROM docentes WHERE nombre=$name";
        $consulta3 = $conexion -> prepare("SELECT * FROM docentes WHERE nombre=".$name);
        $consulta3 ->execute();
        $consulta3 = $consulta3 ->fetchAll();
        if(!$consulta3){
            $mensaje .= "NO HAY consulta PARA MOSTRAR";
        }
        ?>
        document.getElementById("departamento").value = <?php echo "".$name.""; ?>;
        document.getElementById("condicion").value = "<?php echo "".$pru.""; ?>";
    <?php foreach ($consulta3 as $Sql):  ?>

    <?php endforeach; ?>


}
</script>
```

esto mando:

```
SELECT * FROM docentes WHERE nombre=$name;
```

y esto imprime:

```
 SELECT * FROM docentes WHERE nombre=arrayDeCadenas[1];
```

pero quiero que me imprima:

```
 SELECT * FROM docentes WHERE nombre="-->//El texto que escriba en mi input//<---";
```

¿Se puede arreglar eso?

Comment: Saludos te sugiero revisar esto: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1917626/5215609

Comment: Error con las comillas

Comment: Tambien podrias usar Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer el problema esta en el acceso al elemento del arreglo el cual lo tiene entre comillas $name = "arrayDeCadenas[1];"; y debe ser sin comillas para acceder $name = arrayDeCadenas[1];

Te sugiero utilizar ajax para realizar este tipo de operaciones

ejemplo:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: codigo.php,
        success: function(respuesta) {
            console.log(respuesta);
        },
        error: function() {
            console.log("No se ha podido obtener la información");
        }
    });

y en tu archivo codigo.php




    $lastname = "arrayDeCadenas[0];";
            $name = "arrayDeCadenas[1];";
            $pru = "SELECT * FROM docentes WHERE nombre=$name";
            $consulta3 = $conexion -> prepare("SELECT * FROM docentes WHERE nombre=".$name);
            $consulta3 ->execute();
            $consulta3 = $consulta3 ->fetchAll();
            if(!$consulta3){
                $mensaje .= "NO HAY consulta PARA MOSTRAR";
            }
           foreach ($consulta3 as $Sql):  

        endforeach; 
echo "respuesta";//puedes regresar los valores en json
```

?>